# Problema con directorios en archivos jar

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo el siguiente problema, es que estoy intentando acceder a las imágenes de mi aplicación desde un archivos jar, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa(NO el archivo JAR) solo el archivo .java, accede a las imagenes, pero cuando empaqueto el programa en el .JAR y lo ejecuto, las imágenes no se muestran, nos se a que se deba esto, las imagenes estan en una carpeta que esta dentro de la carpeta `src`, la carpeta la nombre `"imagenes"` y las clases estan dentro del paquete main dentro de la misma `src`. Estoy utilizando intellij IDEA.

Aquí esta el código de como tengo las rutas:

```
guardar = new JMenuItem("Guardar", new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/save.png"));
```

Comment: Muestra como tienes la ruta de la imágenes

Comment: `src/imagenes/imagen.png` @RaulCacacho

Comment: asi la la tienes en el codigo??

Comment: Si @RaulCacacho

Comment: prueba solo con esto /imagenes/imagen.png

Comment: Edita la pregunta y seria mejor para ayudarte muestra el codigo donde tines esta ruta

Comment: ya edite. Probe ya de distintas formas, con:

`../imagenes/..`,  /imagenes/ y imagenes/ y aun nada.

@RaulCacacho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como src no es una carpeta normal si no una dentro del proyecto puedes hacerlo de esa manera este un ejemplo para hacer un `ImputStream` y para leer la imagen puedes modificarlo para adaptarlo al proyecto

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/imagenes/save.png");
Image logo = ImageIO.read(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi Solucion en Spring Boot en el caso de una Imagen para un reporte PDF con iText 5.3:

```
Resource resourceImagen = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/images/boletin-header1.png");
InputStream streamImage = resourceImagen.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(streamImage);
imageHeader = Image.getInstance(bytes);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace este código: puede que otros usuarios con el mismo problema más adelante lo vean y no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer].