# Iconos, JFrame y archivos .JAR. Java

Tags: java, jframe, icono

Sé modificar el icono de un JFrame, mi problema es que cuando exporto a .JAR retorna la taza de café como icono principal del JFrame. He probado distintos tipos de exportación, por si acaso, pero ninguna conserva los resultados de las dos líneas de código que personalizan el icono del JFrame que vendrían a ser las siguientes;

```
Image icon = new ImageIcon("./imagenes/icono_test3.png").getImage();
this.setIconImage(icon);
```

Incluso he probado a tener el icono en la ruta relativa a la ubicación en la que reside el .JAR, sin resultados positivos.

Utilizo Eclipse y la carpeta imágenes es hermana de la carpeta src. He visto aplicaciones en formato .JAR en las que se ha personalizado el look & feel de los botones de la aplicación, luego que conservan los recursos de imágenes asociados, por lo que considero que es posible exportar el .JAR de manera que el icono principal del JFrame se mantenga personalizado. He probado una solución sugerida para un problema similar, [Esta solución de aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154795/problema-con-directorios-en-archivos-jar), pero me devuelve una excepción que es la siguiente;

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Luego o no he entendido la solución o no se aplica a mi caso. ¿Qué puedo hacer para mantener el icono personalizado cuando exporto a .JAR?.

Comment: que tipo de proyecto es en eclipse? [tag:ant], [tag:maven], [tag:gradle]?

Comment: Ni ant, ni maven, ni gradle. Solo SE v16... aunque creo que tengo la opción de trabajar con maven en la versión de eclipse que tengo pero nunca lo he mirado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes probar con esto.

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("rutaExactaDeLaImagen")).getImage());
```

Recuerda  "../" que con los dos puntos retrocedes una carpeta . Espero te haya servido cualquier duda la haces saber.

Comment: Con la ruta absoluta funcionaba... pero añadiendo la carpeta donde se ubica el icono al path del proyecto consigo que la ruta relativa funcione también pero, sin embargo, en ambos casos tengo que mantener una copia del fichero png en el disco duro, es decir, no se integra con el JAR. Si se te ocurre el modo te agradecería que lo comentaras. Gracias.